# Value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I saw this equation on a blackboard today: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$

It got me thinking -- this must oscillate between $1$ and $0$, yes? So then does this sum even have a meaningful value?

Comment: yes, the sequence of partial sum is not convergent. It does'nt converge.

Comment: What you say you saw on the blackboard is not an equation.  If you want a broad generic term, you could write "I saw this expression on the blackboard today:".  Or of course you could just say "I saw this sum on the blackboard today:".

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129479/why-do-some-divergent-series-apparently-seem-to-converge-e-g-grandis-series

Answer (score 19):

This sum is called [Grandi's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series) and does not converge in the usual sense. By usual sense, we mean that if you look at the sequence of partial sums then we get that $$S_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n$ is even},\\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}.\end{cases}$$ Hence, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$ does not exist.

That said, convergence of partial sums is by no means the only way to define convergence. Another popular way of defining convergence is to look at the [Cesàro sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation).
The Cesàro sum of the Grandi's series is $1/2$. The Cesàro sum is defined as the limit of the average of the sequence of partial sums i.e. if we let $$\tilde{S}_n = \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{n} S_m}{n+1},$$ then we have that $$\tilde{S}_n = \begin{cases} \frac12 & \text{if $n$ is odd},\\ \frac12 + \frac1{2n+2}& \text{ if $n$ is even},\end{cases}$$ which converges to $\dfrac12$.

There are also other ways to interpret the value of $\dfrac12$.

For instance, if we were to randomly choose a natural number and if we assign the probability of getting an odd number to be $\dfrac12$ and the probability of getting an even number to be $\dfrac12$, then the expected value of the sum $S_n$ is $\dfrac12$.

Another interpretation is through analytic continuation of the function $$f(x) = 1-x+x^2 - x^3 + \cdots, \, \lvert x \rvert < 1.$$
The function converges to $\dfrac1{1+x}$ on the interval $(-1,1)$. Not surprisingly, the analytic continuation of the function $f(x)$ on the entire complex plane is given by $f_{\text{ac}}(x) = \dfrac1{1+x}$, where $x \in \mathbb{C}\backslash \{-1\}$. Hence, if we plugin the value of $x=1$ in $f_{\text{ac}}(x)$, we get the value of $\frac12$. Hence, $$1 - 1 + 1 -1 + \cdots \underset{\text{ac}}{=} \frac1{2}.$$

There are also other regularization techniques like [Borel summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation), [Ramanujan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) which assign a finite value to sums which do not converge. All these different techniques assign a value of $\dfrac12$ for the Grandi's series.

You can read more about Grandi's series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Grandi%27s_series).

**EDIT**

As @anon points out, the $\zeta$ regularization technique (which is actually closely related to Ramanujan summation technique) can also be used here to get the value of $1-1+1-1+\cdots$. Consider $$g(s) = 1 - \frac1{2^s} + \frac1{3^s} - \frac1{4^s} + \cdots$$ and $$f(s) = 1 + \frac1{2^s} + \frac1{3^s} + \frac1{4^s} + \cdots$$
The series $g(s)$ converges for Real$(s) > 0$ and converges absolutely for Real$(s) >1$. The series $f(s)$ converges for Real$(s) > 1$. In the region, Real$(s)>1$, we have that $$g(s) = 1 - \frac1{2^s} + \frac1{3^s} - \frac1{4^s} + \cdots = \left(1 + \frac1{2^s} + \frac1{3^s} + \frac1{4^s} + \cdots \right) - \left(\frac2{2^s} + \frac2{4^s} + \frac2{6^s} + \frac2{8^s} + \cdots \right) = f(s) - \frac1{2^{s-1}} f(s) = \left(1 - 2^{1-s} \right)f(s).$$

Now analytic continuation of $g(s)$ gives us $\eta(s)$ such that $\eta(s) = (1-2^{1-s}) \zeta(s)$, where $\zeta(s)$ is the analytic continuation of $f(s)$. Hence, plugging in $s=0$, we get that $$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 +\cdots \underset{\text{ac}}{=} \eta(0) = (1-2) \zeta(0) = -\zeta(0) = \frac12,$$ since the value of $\zeta(0) = -\dfrac12$.

Comment: I didn't even know there was another notion of convergence in wich this little monster could converge. Learning something everyday =)

Comment: Very thourough answer Marvis.

Comment: It can also be regularized with the [Dirichlet eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) $$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$ analytically continued to $s=0$.

Comment: when you write "\end{cases}." with the period _outside_ of the "cases" environment, it looks like this: $\displaystyle\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n$ is even} \\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}.$ ${}\qquad{}$ I changed it to $\displaystyle\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}.\end{cases}$ ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the edit. I shall follow this in future.

Comment: @anon Yes. I will add it to the post, citing you, to make the post complete.