# Classification of Series $(-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does it converge or diverge or we can't tell?

$$∑_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$$

Or is there simply no concrete answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The underlying sequence is called the Grandi sequence. If your experience investigating the convergence of this series is like mine, you'll run into the concepts Cesaro summability and Abel summability.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Value of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145688/value-of-sum-n-0-infty-1n)

Comment: 50th puyoy5u0j5jo0oojyj ju5oipl mpnjbp9pp  v ,dass bhx8lk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you are planning to use that sum. I believe that there are physicist who will insist on the expression being a half, but mathematically there is no convergence. The partial sums are zero and one alternatingly, therefore no limit exists.

If you go for the physics approach you will get the value thus:

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n$

Then $(-1)S=S-1$ since the multiplication just shifts the sum by one. Therefore $S=\frac{1}{2}$. This is similiar to the way you determine the value of a geometric series, if you overlook the fact that $S$ is of course undefined in the first place. So if $S$ is to have any value it will be $\frac{1}{2}$ since that's the only value that exhibits the same properties as the Sum.

So if this sum occurs somewhere but you know it must be representative of some finite number because it represents something physical, it's $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I like your initial answer, but some elaboration on why physicists will differ from others (possibly mathematicians) on the existence of the series value and what the value is equal to would be nice :).

Comment: maybe  have a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-cdots-frac112) for an in depth exploration of this type of sum

Comment: @MatthiasKaul Thank you so much, such good answers on that question. I don't understand why everyone answered me like I had no idea what I was asking... Again very interesting answers in that question

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If $\sum a_n$ converges, you must have $a_n \to 0$. Does this happen here?

Comment: Yes, I do know the limit for an doesn't exist so it's not 0. But that doesn't make it diverge, right? If so, my question is how can we classify this series?

Comment: $$ \left( \sum a_n \text{ converges } \implies a_n \to 0\right) \iff \left( a_n \not\to 0 \implies \sum a_n \text{ does not converge.}\right)$$

Comment: @Chapi Its sequence of partial sums is often called ["oscillating"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_oscillation#Oscillation_of_a_sequence), which implies non-convergence. It varies from person to person whether oscillating behavior is considered divergence.

Comment: @pjs36 The definition of a divergent sequence is a sequence that does not converge.

Comment: @DanRobertson Thank you, that was the concept I was missing

Comment: @DanRobertson Thanks, I must have mis-recalled a definition there. I thought I remembered some authors allowing "oscillation" as a third category, but I must be mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

When we say a series converges, we mean that the sequence of partial sums approaches a limit. Let's consider the sequence of partial sums of your series: $$\begin{matrix}-1 & = & -1 \\ -1 + 1 &= &0 \\ -1 + 1 - 1 &= &-1\end{matrix}$$
and so on, so it keeps alternating from $-1$ to $0$. It therefore doesn't approach a unique value. The series therefore diverges.

Also, when you ask "is there no concrete answer", it's clear you're misunderstanding. A given series either converges or diverges, and there's no in-between. When we say a series diverges, we only mean that it doesn't converge.